# $E[X^2]$ in terms of Theta Notation

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a a fair dice and throw it $n$ times. If the number of times that the result is less or equal to $4$ is $X$, we earn $X^2$ dollars.

1) If $n = 2$ then how much is $E[X^2]$

2) Which one of the following is correct

$E[X^2] = \Theta(n\lg n)$

$E[X^2] = \Theta(n^2)$

None of the above

Comment: At the very least can you answer part 1) so we can see that you understand what the distribution $X$ and the meaning of expected value are?  At the moment, it is unclear just *how* much of an explanation you require, whether we have to go through word by word and explain each and every minute detail.  Do you know what it means for a function $f(n)$ to be $\Theta(g(n))$?

Comment: Yes, I know the Theta notation very well. I need the answer only for the second question, I have solved the first one but I have put it all there so that you can understand the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$X \sim Bin(n, \frac23)$$

$$Var(X)=n \left(\frac23\right) \left( \frac13 \right)$$

$$E(X)= \frac23 n$$

Find $$E(X^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Note $X \sim \text{Binom}(n, p)$ where $p=2/3$.

Hint 2: $$E[X^2] = \text{Var}(X) + (E[X])^2$$

> $$E[X^2] = np(1-p) + n^2 p^2$$